# How do I display time/date like Instagram?

Tags: ios, swift

I've done a lot of research but couldn't find it, how do I display timestamp like Instagram style. Example: 1h, 2w or 3s ago.

I don't want to display the time, but instead the duration since the post uploaded.

What I've got is the `Date().description` of each post.

Comment: Use `NSDateComponents` to get the components you want to display. Then format it how you want.

Comment: @Brandon Actually, use `DateComponentsFormatter`.

Comment: @rmaddy; Nice. :D I completely forgot that existed.